# Tutorial about how to move ackermann vehicle

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have created an ackermann vehicle. (http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_vehicle)
Does anyone know if there are anywhere tutorials on how to control/move this vehicle and to link a map to a vehicle?
I searched for some tutorials regarding ackermann vehicle but could not find any.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207780/tutorial-about-how-to-move-ackermann-vehicle/) by [StupuAlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22101/stupualin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ackermann_vehicle subscribes to a`ackermann_msgs/AckermannDriveStamped` on the `ackermann_cmd` topic.

You should be able to use the ackermann_qt node to control your simulated vehicle: http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_qt?distro=hydro

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1